# Is it possible to post a picture to facebook,twitter using Microsoft.Phone.Task library in wp 7.5

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, post, photo

I am using ShareLinkTask to post URL to social websites like twitter and facebook. Along with the URL ,i want to add a picture URI and the picture should display in sites.Is it possible ? Also is it possible to share when a different user is using the app ?since only one account is in sync and always the posting to sites happens with the account in sync with the phone.Can we have the login again while sharing so that the person using the app can post to his wall?

Answer (score 1):

**No.** Tasks are somewhat more limited compared to a direct API layer implementation that you would get through a service-based SDK. They are always bound to the accounts that are associated with the device and you cannot log the user in/out with those from the app, unless the user himself decides to switch the accounts.

Also, at this point you cannot attach media content to a `ShareLinkTask` unless you already uploaded it through a service (such as IMGUR) and just posting a link to it.